# Morphism where the algebra receives the item's position

Tags: recursion-schemes, catamorphism

Which one is the appropriate morphism (recursion scheme) to use when the given item's position (index, or path) is required in the transformer function?

A simple example would be transforming a list `["foo", "bar", "qux"]` into the string `"foo, bar, and qux"`. The current element's position is needed to know when to insert the `and`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the index part of the structure so it is available to the recursion scheme. An ad-hoc way to do this is to define a `foldWithIndex` function:

```
foldWithIndex :: (Foldable t, Num i) => (i -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldWithIndex f z t = snd $ foldr f' (0, z) t
    where
        f' z (i, x) = (i + 1, f i z x)
```

This function takes an operator for combining the elements which also considers the index:

```
foldWithIndex combine "" ["foo", "bar", "qux"]
    where
        combine 0 s1 s2 = s1 ++ s2
        combine 1 s1 s2 = s1 ++ " and " ++ s2
        combine _ s1 s2 = s1 ++ ", " ++ s2
```

results in `"foo, bar and qux"`.

For a more general approach see [`Data.Foldable.WithIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/indexed-traversable-0.1.1/docs/Data-Foldable-WithIndex.html), which provides a foldable typeclass that also takes an index into account.